# Problems theming Drupal 8 + SwiftMailer contact email

Tags: drupal, themes, swiftmailer, drupal-8

I'm trying to use swiftmailer to theme my contact email in a Drupal 8 site, but having some difficulties.I'm trying to use the default theme file for swiftmailer but it renders all the body. How can I access each field individually?

What I want to do is something like this:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * The default template file for e-mails.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - subject: The subject.
 * - body: The message content.
 * - message: The $message array created and used in the mail building
 *   procedure. Its content varies between cases, but typically contains at
 *   least the following elements:
 *   - id: The message identifier.
 *   - module: The module that handles the building of the message.
 *   - key: The key of the message.
 *   - to: The recipient email address.
 *   - from: The email address of the sender.
 *   - langcode: The langcode to use to compose the e-mail.
 *   - params: The message parameters.
 *
 * This template may be overriden by module and/or mail key, using any of the
 * following template names:
 * - swiftmailer.html.twig: global, used by default.
 * - swiftmailer--mymodule.html.twig: only emails sent by the module "mymodule".
 * - swiftmailer--mymodule--test.html.twig: only emails by the module
 *   "mymodule" with key "test".
 *
 * @see template_preprocess()
 * @see template_preprocess_swiftmailer()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    table tr td {
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 12px;
    }

    td .field {
      width: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <table width="800px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td class="field">Nome</td>
      <td>{{ body.name }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field">Email</td>
      <td>{{ body.mail }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field">Motivo</td>
      <td>{{ body.motivo }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field">Titulo</td>
      <td>{{ body.subject }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field">Mensagem</td>
      <td>{{ body.message }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems something simple but it's taking too much time. All "body.something" are blank.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Parameters for emails are usually (of course it depends on implementation) in `message.params`. I suggest you use `message.params` to access the variables you need.

Also, to help, you can use the devel module and use `{{ dump() }}` to print out all the variables that are available in that theme file and from there discover where your stuff is.

Comment: dump(body) is working but is not really interested. 
dump(message.params) display nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The variables are all listed at the top of the template...

```
 * Available variables:
 * - subject: The subject.
 * - body: The message content.
 * - message: The $message array created and used in the mail building
 *   procedure. Its content varies between cases, but typically contains at
 *   least the following elements:
 *   - id: The message identifier.
 *   - module: The module that handles the building of the message.
 *   - key: The key of the message.
 *   - to: The recipient email address.
 *   - from: The email address of the sender.
 *   - langcode: The langcode to use to compose the e-mail.
 *   - params: The message parameters.
```

You would use in the template like this:-

```
{{ subject }}
{{ body }}
{{ message.to }}
{{ message.params.YOUR_PARAM }}
```

Etc...

Comment: message.params.field_name does not work for me.
fields are all display in once in body, I do not know how to access field individually.

Comment: Do you have a mail send function where you define the PARAMs?